# How to generate a PDF with multiple HTML div elements on separate pages using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, pdf

In my code I have multiple `<div class="value-group">` which I'm trying them into a PDF. I want to get each of the divs in the on a separate page in a PDF. Each of `value-group` contains a bunch of text and an image (img width = `95%`, height = `calc(30vw / 95%)`).

I've tried looping through `value-group`s, and adding them one by one but I am getting a blank pdf, with the number of `value-group`s.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>

function generatePdf() {
  window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
  window.html2canvas = html2canvas;
  var pdf = new jsPDF();
  const valueGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.value-group');
  
  valueGroups.forEach((valueGroup, index) => {
    if (index !== 0) {
      pdf.addPage();
    }
    pdf.html(valueGroup, {
      callback: function () {
        if (index !== valueGroups.length - 1) {
          pdf.addPage();
        }
      },
      autoPaging: true
    });
  });

  pdf.save('exported_bookmarks.pdf');
}

const savePdfButton = document.getElementById('save-pdf-btn');
savePdfButton.addEventListener('click', generatePdf);

//div roughly looks like this - 
  <div class="value-group">
    <p class="col2">${col2}</p>
    <p class="abt">${col7}</p>
    <img src="${col3}">
  </div>
```

What should I do? Any way to get each `value-group` div on a separate page in the PDF?